# Ease while writing code in G1ant software

Tags: g1ant

I successfully download the giant software and created my first program but I faced difficulty in typing some symbols like '<<< ENTER>>>' . Giant doesn't take <<< symbol as entered from keyboard. For this I  have to copy  ⋘ symbol from sample program. So in future we have to copy these symbols or is there any easy way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'Ctrl' + '<' in your keyboard and you will get '<<<>>>'.
Hope it will help